# Azure App Service Memory Use Diagnostics

Tags: azure, memory-usage

Our ASP.NET website hosted on Azure as an App Service is experience periodic huge memory spikes. In the portal I will see it hover around 1GB all day then spike up to 5GB over the course of an hour or two.  This happens without any associated increase in request volume.  I'm wondering what tools are available in Azure to dig deeper into the cause.  Is there an easy way I can dig into what objects are being allocated, for instance?  Is it possible to get a more fine grained view of memory use (better than 1 hour resolution) so I can try to tie events in the logs to the start of the memory spike?

Answer (score 1):

Just add Application Insights to your code to get a detailed view of what's going on in your application.

**Overview:**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/

**Set up Application Insights for ASP.NET**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net/